# Experiment: extending a native object

Tags: javascript

I was reading up on some discussions about extending native objects in javascript. Extending native objects in current browsers seem to have much less disadvantages than they used to. Certainly considering we have more control about how objects are extended through methods such as:

```
 Object.defineProperty(<some parameters...>)
```

A big risk that however remains is that of collision between different code/libraries, resulting in unexpected behavior.

Risks of naming collision (and global clobbering) can be reduced by namespacing your own functions. So I thought why do we not do this if we extend the native object? Of course execution context is a problem but we can fix that with bind(), making native functions of that object available in our extended functionality. So i created the following to extend the Element object:

```
// Define the extend function
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'extend', { value: function(namespace, object) {
    var cache = {};
    // Create  the namespace and make sure on invocation the Element is bound
    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, namespace, { value: function() {
        var objectCheck = typeof cache[Element.prototype.constructor.name] !== 'undefined';
        if(objectCheck && typeof cache[Element.prototype.constructor.name][namespace] !== 'undefined'){
            console.log('cache used');
            return cache[Element.prototype.constructor.name][namespace];
        } else {
            var extended = Element.prototype[namespace].extended;
            for (var e in extended) {
                extended[e] = extended[e].bind(this);
            }

            if(!objectCheck)
                cache[Element.prototype.constructor.name] = {};
            cache[Element.prototype.constructor.name][namespace] = extended;
        }

        return extended;
    }});

    this[namespace].extended = object;
    return this;
}});

// Extend the Element prototype with an attr function in 
// the namespace 'namespace' or ofcourse whatever function
Element.prototype.extend('namespace',{
    attr: function(name, value) {
        if(arguments.length === 1) {
            return this.getAttribute(name);
        } else {
            this.setAttribute(name, value);
            return this;
        }
    }
});
```

It all looks good when check it out on an actual element, the namespace is there and inside it we find our 'attr' function. We can invoke it like this:

```
document.querySelector('.a-css-class').namespace().attr('class')
// returns 'a-css-class'
```

The code could be refactored further to dynamically extend all sorts of objects. However I'm curious, what could this mean for performance, does this experiment make sense? The main question, is this any better than extending directly?

EDIT (based on Bergi's comments regarding performance):

It would be possible to cache the created function in the outer function. Let's see if I can come up with an implementation.

EDIT 2:

Added a simple caching function to make sure not all namespaced methods are create each en every invocation.

EDIT 3:

The updated code. In an attempt to make extending native object safer, the following code was produced. It might prevent naming collision. Thanks @Bergi:

```
/**
 * Extend a (NATIVE) object with a namespace. See below for an example
 */
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'extend', { value: function(namespace, object) {
    function Wrapper(that) {
        this.that = that;
    }
    Wrapper.prototype = object;
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, namespace, { value: function() {
        return new Wrapper(this);
    }});
}});

// This example uses the Element object, but it could be any object
Element.prototype.extend('namespace',{
    attr: function(name, value) {
        if(arguments.length === 1) {
            return this.that.getAttribute(name);
        } else {
            this.that.setAttribute(name, value);
            return this;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Your current `extended` object doesn't seem to work. You are binding all the methods to the current element, the `.namespace()` invoked on a second element (of the same type) will return the wrong methods.

Comment: I did some testing you're totaly right, however the wrapper solution seems to be working like a charm. All in all I think this experiment was not a very successful one. Perhaps there are some other methods of extending native objects more safely. I'll post my updated code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm curious, what could this mean for performance

Your current code means that whenever you call `namespace()`, you create a new object and lots of bound functions, which will impact performance quite heavily for large namespaces.

I would recommend to let your `namespace` method return a wrapper object with an `element: this` property, which inherits all the methods that can be called on it. You'd use `this.element.getAttribute` then instead of `this.getAttribute`:

```
Element.prototype.extend = function(namespace, object) {
    function Wrapper(el) {
        this.element = el;
    }
    Wrapper.prototype = object;

    Element.prototype[namespace] = function() {
       return new Wrapper(this);
    };
};
```

> The main question, is this any better than extending directly?

Not much. You still are defining `extend` and `namespace` properties on the `Element.prototype`, and for these two properties all the arguments against extending the DOM are still valid. You *might* lower the risk of collisions with more common names (`attr`), but it's not better than just defining a `namespace_attr` method.

Comment: Thanks for your comments :), regarding the first point with the wrapper object. I don't exactly see how I would implement this and what it would improve in performance. Could you explain or show? Regarding the namespacing I think this is a very valid point, instead of creating this overhead prefixing would be much more effecient.

Comment: This does seem much more elegant, however you do have the 'this.element' compromise.

Comment: Hm, we could apply a bit more magic and put something like `Wrapper.prototype = {attr: function(){return object.attr.apply(this.element, arguments);}};` instead of `object` directly.